# How to make color gradient look smooth?

Tags: color-management

[image: my model with a color gradient]

Hey guys, how would i go about making this color gradient look smooth, without all the jagged lines on the material?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the *UV* output of the *Texture Coordinate*, so the gradient is projected according to the unwrap, instead use the *Generated* output, which will use the whole object, and put a *Converter > Separate XYZ* node in order to choose the direction of the gradient:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!